# Move selection after a DOM element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, range, selection

I'm currently building a Markdown editor for the web. Markdown tags are previewed in realtime by appending their HTML equivalents via the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) interface. Following code is used, which should be working according to MDN:

```
var range = document.createRange()
var selection = window.getSelection()

range.setStart(textNode, start)
range.setEnd(textNode, end + 2)

surroundingElement = document.createElement('strong')
range.surroundContents(surroundingElement)

var cursorRange = document.createRange()
cursorRange.setStartAfter(surroundingElement)

selection.removeAllRanges()
selection.addRange(cursorRange)
```

---

Firefox works: Some **bold** text

[image]

Chrome not: Some **bold text**

[image]

Any suggestions what could be wrong? Information on this subject are rare.

---

## Answer

Thanks to @Tim Down, I fixed it using the invisible character workaround he describes in one of the links mentioned in his answer. This is the code I'm using now:

```
var range = document.createRange()

range.setStart(textNode, start)
range.setEnd(textNode, end + 2)

surroundingElement = document.createElement('strong')
range.surroundContents(surroundingElement)

var selection = window.getSelection()
var cursorRange = document.createRange()

var emptyElement = document.createTextNode('\u200B')
element[0].appendChild(emptyElement)

cursorRange.setStartAfter(emptyElement)

selection.removeAllRanges()
selection.addRange(cursorRange)
```

Comment: Please remove the answer from the question and post is as an actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that WebKit has fixed ideas about where the caret (or a selection boundary) can go and is selecting an amended version of your range when you call the selection's `addRange()` method. I've written about this a few times on Stack Overflow; here are a couple of examples:

- [Set cursor after span element inside contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813895/set-cursor-after-span-element-inside-contenteditable-div)
- [How to set caret/cursor position in a contenteditable div between two divs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098303/how-to-set-caret-cursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-div-between-two-divs)

Comment: @ream88: Sadly not. There isn't really a fix, only nasty workarounds.

Comment: Fixed it, using the invisible char workaround. Thank you very much, hopefully these inconsistencies will be fixed someday.